# Bucketing not optimized in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have bucketed table based on column flightnum(10 buckets), data size is approx 700MB, bucketing enforced as well.

When I am executing the query : 
**select count(flightnum) from flight_buck where flightnum=10;**
getting the response in approx 46s. Total number of mappers were 27.

When executing the same query on non bucketed table with same data :
**select count(flightnum) from flight_temp where flightnum=10;** 
getting the response in approx 47s. Total number of mappers used were 30.

Why I am getting the response in same amount of time?

Answer (score 3):

Bucketing helps join to be faster, to increase the simple SELECT speed you have to use partitioned tables.
Try to partition table by flightnum and run again the selects.

Why does this happen ?

Let's create a bucketed not partitioned table like this:

```
create table `t1b`( 
  `exchange` string,
  `stock_symbol` string,
  `date` string,
  `stock_price_open` float,
  `stock_price_high` float,
  `stock_price_low` float,
  `stock_price_close` float,
  `stock_volume` int,
  `stock_price_adj_close` float)
clustered by ( `stock_symbol` ) sorted by ( `date` ) into 306 buckets;
```

And let's fill it with data... There are as many reducers as many buckets because each reducer will process only record with the same keys and will store the data into its file using the sorting you like, in this case by date

[image]

Let's look at HDFS...

Please note what we got.. 306 files (buckets) ...

[image]

and inside each of them there are records which have the same clustering key...

[image]

But all the files are into the same folder, and when SELECTing with hive there is no way to understand which files hold the value we are looking for, so bucketing with no partitioning does not speed up select because there are no info about where are the data we are looking for.

What does bucketing do ? When you are JOINing data, the whole bucket can be loaded into RAM and we can get a fast join in MAP instead to get a slow join in REDUCE.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: But if we use bucketing with partitioning, how it will speed up the response? Speeding up can be done only by partition, I guess.

Comment: Buckets can increase join speed. The intuition is that each bucket is small in size and has all the records with the same key. It can be loaded wholy in ram when the combiner run in the map phase. This increase the join speed. You know: when you are joining tables you are looking for records with the same key. Partitions and buckets help different stages in map reducer jobs.

Comment: Combiner is a little reducer which can work only on local data and can join data.